# Adding coordinate 0 on log scale in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

I am trying to plot a graph using `tikz/pgfplot`. I want the x-axis to be in log scale, I have got it using `xmode=log`. However, while using linear plot, the coordinate `(0,0)` is displayed on the graph. However, on `log` scale the coordinate `(0,0)` does not appear. Well, its understood that `log(0)` is undefined. But I have data in linear scale, and I just want to plot it as though it appears to be in log scale.

Here is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    xtick= {0,1,2,3,4},]
    \addplot[blue,mark=*]coordinates {
        (0,0)
        (1,1)
        (2,2)
        (3,3)
        (4,4)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image: Current results]

Comment: I guess you could do it if you had infinitely large paper.

Comment: Even if you try and cheat with a `(0.01,0.01)` plot point, it's unable to place your wanted 0 `x tick` (obviously), so...

Comment: Tried it with 0.00001, produces a very weird graph.

Comment: The more you try approaching zero, the weirder the graph appears, since it's a logarithmic scale. The space between 0.00001 and 1 is way bigger than any of the other ones.